# Azure mobile services Xamarin Android Issues

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.android

I am trying to get all the rows of a table (it only has about 12-20 rows in it) from Azure. I am able to get this to work flawlessly on Windows phone but when it comes to Xamarin Android, it fails miserably. The worst part is I can't even log the exception because it never enters the catch.

Here is basically what it looks like:

```
IMobileServiceTable _table = mobileServiceClient.getTable<MyType>
Collection <MyType> rows = null;
try{

     rows = _table.ToCollectionAsync().Result

}catch (Exception e){

   //Never comes here
}

//BUT never comes here either!!

 do stuff with rows.
```

Strangle enough if I change the catch clause to

```
     catch(Exception)
```

it will enter the catch but then I can't log it or see what the exception is.

Comment: Why are you doing `.Result`?

Answer (score 1):

So turns out this was not the issue. Because it is an async function, the data does EVENTUALLY get populated.